# input type datepicker with runat="server"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to input value datepicker with input type html5 to database SQL Server.

Here the aspx

```
<input type="text"  id="txtRRDate" name="txtRRDate" />
<script>
     $(function () {
        $("#txtRRDate").datepicker();
     });
</script>'
```

and when i want to return value from that input type i put runat="server" so i can call it on the logic

```
    Dim cls As New clsMain
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim strWhere As String = ""
    strSQL = "UPDATE TRXHeader"
    strSQL = strSQL & "SET RRReceivedDate = '" + txtRRDate.Value + "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE PONo = '" + txtPOno.Text + "'"
```

But when I run it, the datepicker doesn't show up.

Any suggestions where the problem is?

Thanks in advance, sorry for bad English.

Comment: date picker worked when i run the input type without runat="server"

Comment: It will work fine even with runat. Just be sure about class name and the script of the date picker.

Comment: hmm i dont really know about the script and finally i can get it work with request.form("txtRRDate") to input value into database

Comment: See the documentation for ASP.NET. It works fine with the both.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that when you put the runat="server" attribute to the input the client id of that input will change. so calling .datepicker() function on the element $("#txtRRDate") will not work as the id txtRRDate doesen't exist in the client document.

You can try what i always do :

```
`<input type="text"  id="txtRRDate" name="txtRRDate" runat="server" />
<script>
     $(function () {
        $("#<%= txtRRDate.ClientID%>").datepicker();
     });
</script>'`
```

now the function .datepicker() is called on the client id of the control